# Weblogic JMS Queue inter-server communication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic, jms-topic

We have a use case where we want to read messages from JMS queue maintained in  weblogic server from another weblogic server.

Setup is something like this -

Weblogic Server -1 Domain-1 has a distributed JMS queue Q1
Weblogic Server -2 Domain-2 has a Application A

Application A want to read messages from Q1

Questions:

a. First of all, Is it possible for Application-A to read messages from weblogic JMS queue which is in some other server ?

b. Can we setup Q1 on Server-2 as foreign JMS queue, so that Application A can access it as local resource.

c. I understand when there is only one server, we can access it using hostname i.e jms://hostname/connectionFactory/jmsQueuename, however In clustered setup, how do we access the JMS resource ? how the URL will look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. Yes. You will have to make remote jndi calls to load the connection factory and the queue.
b. You can do that but a better way is to use a bridge between both domains, therefore your application does not need to be aware of your architecture and the bridge will take in chare load balancing and failover
c. cluster addresses look like :,:, etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot Emmanuel, a followup question - with JMS bridge we need to establish domain trust, which requires one server to know the credential of another server. Is there an alternative design that save is from credential sharing problem ?

Comment: Even if you make a connection on a remote destination (queue) you will need to provide credentials for security reasons. In both situations credentials will be required.

Comment: We have similar kind of setup, but it doesn't maintain UnitOfOrder while reading messages from the JMS Topic. Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks.